# REGEX to extract word connected to nearest semicolon?

Tags: regex

I'm attempting to extract a series of data values from a text file.

The values are in the format: `<MODIFIER NAME1 VALUE; MODIFIER NAME2 VALUE;>`

For the purposes of the current task that I have, I only care about extracting the VALUE that is situated next to each semicolon. What would the REGEX command look like that would isolate each of these VALUES (preferably so that I backreference all values in the replacement part of my processing.) I believe that ^(.*?); is somehow used, but I'm not seeing how to isolate only the word that is attached to the semicolon in a group for backreference use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact syntax depends on the language, but the following regex should do it

```
"(\w+);"
```

I used the c# syntax.  In other languages, the syntax might change a bit, but the actual regex remains the same.

where `\w` means any letter(it also includes 0-9 and '_), and the parenthesis signify that you capture the group inside.

if you want only letters, you can change the `\w` to `[a-zA-Z]` (again, different languages may or may not have different syntax for this)

I use [This reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) to reference my c# regex syntax.  If you're using another language, that will also have something similar somewhere.

Comment: So you're saying that the look for syntax might look like: <^(.*?)(\w*)a; ? By the way, what does the a stand for (probably a dumb question)

Comment: @JohnKaybern  i didn't intend to write the `a` i actually meant to press `;`  fixed.

Comment: Ah okay, that explains that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JohnKaybern what language are you doing this in?

Comment: well I'm using a shell script for the processing and then Java for the GUI front-end, so for this example, only shell (or more specifically, sed)

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out exactly what will come betwen the < and the (\W+) that I will use to back reference the data I care about... i.e. what REGEX I can use to describe' MODIFIER NAME '